# Confusion about Gödel's Completeness Theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am interested in the following question just because it feels as if I am not able to figured it out on my own. It seems there is some mistake in my thinking.

Let $T$ be a theory in some first-order language and $\sigma$ a sentence in the same language. The Completeness Theorem says that $T \vdash \sigma$ if and only if $T \models \sigma$.

To me, it seems that the first statement depends only on logical axioms (how to deduce etc.) while the second statement depends on the existence or non-existence of certain models of $T$ which is (on first glance) a question of set-theoretical axioms.

I cannot believe that the existence of models of $T$ satisfying $\sigma$ is independent of the choice of set theory. This cannot be true.

Thank you for your help!

---

Edit making the question very concrete:

Suppose that a theory $T$ in a language (say the theory $\mathsf{ACF}$ of algebraically closed field together with one sentences $\sigma$, in the language of rings)
has no models under the assumption of $\mathsf{ZFC}+ \mathsf{GCH}$
. Hence, by logical operation, one can infer a contradiction from $T$
(Incompleteness Theorem). But since there is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ where natural numbers coincide with the ones from our original model of  $\mathsf{ZFC}+ \mathsf{GCH}$, the proof of the contradiction can also be encoded in the ''smaller'' model, and this model therefore does not contain a model of $T$.

Is this correct?

Comment: $\vDash$ is general; it is used not only for mathematical theories having mathematical structures as models. See e.g [Completeness of Syllogism](https://homepages.uc.edu/~martinj/History_of_Logic/Aristotle/Syllogistic/Corcoran%20-%20Completeness%20of%20an%20Ancient%20Logic.pdf): the amount of "set theory" needed is quite small.

Comment: You are right, this result depends on your set-theoretic assumptions, particularly regarding the axiom of choice. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem

Comment: More specifically [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem#Relationship_to_the_compactness_theorem) section.

Comment: Okay, thank you all three.
To make my question a bit more specific: Suppose that a theory $T$ has no models under the assumption of $\mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{GCH}$. Hence, by logical operation, one can infer a contradiction from $T$ (Incompleteness Theorem). But the contradiction follows without set-theoretical assumption, consequently $T$ has no models under the assumption of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.
Is this correct?

Comment: That's worth editing into the question, but the obvious response is $T+\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{GCH}$ is what lacks models due to having a contradiction, not necessarily $T$, which is liable to have models. They won't be models _of_ $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{GCH}$, but they'll be models whose existence _is provable with_ $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{GCH}$.

Comment: I suggest reading up on the Henkin Construction: it doesn't take much to put together a model of a first-order theory. This is why we wind up getting countable nonstandard models of e.g. the reals or even ZFC (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox).

Comment: @DanielW.: Well, you have to be careful about what exactly "$T$" is.  For instance, consider the theory $T=\{y:y="\exists x(x\neq x)"\wedge \,\mathsf{GCH}\}$.  Assuming GCH this theory is inconsistent but assuming the negation of GCH it is consistent!

Comment: Moreover, even for examples that are not silly like this, the consistency of a theory can depend on your metatheory!  For instance, if $T$ is ZFC itself, then (assuming ZFC is consistent) $T$ cannot be proven to be consistent in ZFC, but it can be proven to be consistent in stronger set theories.

Comment: But you are correct that the completeness theorem has the not-at-all-obvious consequence that the existence of a model of a reasonably defined theory is *absolute* between models of set theory that have the same natural numbers, since it is equivalent to the non-existence of certain finite sequences of natural numbers (namely, such sequences that encode a proof of a contradiction in the theory).

Comment: Thank you! I include my comment as part of the question and, if you want, you can write that as an answer.

Comment: Imo the symbol $\models$ should always be understood relative to a certain class/set/notion of model.

Comment: Looking at your concrete question, there's a slight subtlety: $T$ has to exist in all models of set theory you're considering. Normally this isn't an issue, since $T$ is usually constructible, but there are applications of completeness in cases where $T$ has some set-theoretic weirdness going on.